# Scaling in flex - exclude some children?

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary, scaling

i'm trying to build a webmap application in flex.
for ths, 've got a fxg-file which represents the maps.
it's in a 
also there are some elements, like POIs, text et cetera in this group.
i zoom the  with scaleX and scaleY, this works just fine for the map.

but the problem is: ALL childen zoom also. i don't want this. they should stay the same place on the map and the same size.

heres some code
the as function

```
<fx:Script>

    <![CDATA[
        import mx.skins.Border; 
        [Bindable]
        public var hoehe:Number = 1;
        [Bindable]
        public var breite:Number = 1;

        protected function zoom_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            hoehe = zoom.value;
            breite =  zoom.value;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

and the

```
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%"   baseline="10">

<s:Group scaleX="{breite}" scaleY="{hoehe}"  id="mapView" > <!-- zum zoomen -->

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" > <!-- Enthält alle Objekte -->
    <images:karte  id="kartePanel" height="630" width="430" />
    <images:akw   id="akw1" scaleX="0.2" scaleY="0.2" top="158" left="190" />       
    <components:akwView x="154" y="131" resizeMode="scale">
    </components:akwView>
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

componentsLakwView contains some labels etc. this should not be resized?

Comment: I don't have a good feel for what's going on.  How is the zoomChange_Handler being fired?  If you only want to change the scale value of the actual map; then you probably don't want to change the scale values on a group that contains other components.

Comment: I was having this issue with backgroundImage repeat-x scaling as part of a custom component that caused it to become extremely pixelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate zoom for those children with inverse value - for example, if you apply zoom 2.0 to parent, apply 1/2.0 = 0.5 scale to those children, and their size will be constant.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate your map application to several layers, each layer contain a specific set of items. For example, the bottom layer is the map only, one layer for text, one for POIs... So you only need to scale on map layer and adjust the position of items on the other layers. This approach also gives you advantage of hiding some layers if not necessary.

Comment: From what I read, you have a parent Group call mapView which contains the map (karte) and other item (akw/akwView, can't translate it so i don't know what it is, but guess it is the item you dont want to scale). 
They are separate layers, sure. The problem is you are scaling the Group mapView, this Group is the parent of all layers and then, all of them will be scale too.
You should move **scaleX="{breite}" scaleY="{hoehe}"** to **karte** component. For the others, adjust the **x, y, top, left** based on **breite and hoehe**. I think multiplication is sufficient.

Comment: sounds like another good idea. but the first works fine - anyhow: thank you!